# glitchy jquery div carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so i've made a jquery carousel which you can see here: http://teste.boleiafacil.com/ (it's the one in the end of the page

this is the jquery:

```
//highlights slide animation
    var prdlength = $(".rproducts").length;
    var prdleft = 1;
    var i = 0;
    function swapC() {
        i++;
        prdleft++;
        $(".rproducts").each(function(){
            $(this).animate({"left":"-" + prdleft + "px"}, 10);
            if (prdleft == 180){
                $(this).appendTo(".rproductswrapper");
                prdleft = 0;
            }
        });
        if (i == prdlength) {
            i = 0
        }
        window.setTimeout(function() { swapC() }, 10);
    }
    $(window).on("load", swapC);
```

the problem is when the divs get appended to the end of the wrapper it looks glitchy.

how can i fix this?

Comment: Try animating the entire container `.rproductswrapper`. You can then see when to remove an image using the jQuery [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) property.

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping your function in a document ready rather than window load, the shorthand for it is:

```
$(function(){
//code here
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this will help the OP.